# Can the R console support background tasks or interrupts (event-handling)?

Tags: r, event-handling, interrupt, background-process

While working in an R console, I'd like to set up a background task that monitors a particular connection and when an event occurs, another function (an alert) is executed.  Alternatively, I can set things up so that an external function simply sends an alert to R, but this seems to be the same problem: it is necessary to set up a listener.

I can do this in a dedicated process of R, but I don't know if this is feasible from within a console.  Also, I'm not interested in interrupting R if it is calculating a function, but alerting or interrupting if the console is merely waiting on input.

Here are three use cases:

1. The simplest possible example is watching a file.  Suppose that I have a file called "latestData.csv" and I want to monitor it for changes; when it changes, `myAlert()` is executed.  (One can extend it to do different things, but just popping up with a note that a file has changed is useful.)
2. A different kind of monitor would watch for whether a given machine is running low on RAM and might execute a `save.image()` and terminate.  Again, this could be a simple issue of watching a file produced by an external monitor that saves the output of `top` or some other command.
3. A different example is like another recent SO question, about : [have R halt the EC2 machine it's running on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273616/have-r-halt-the-ec2-machine-its-running-on).  If an alert from another machine or process tells the program to save & terminate, then being able to listen for that alert would be great.

At the moment, I suspect there are two ways of handling this: via Rserve and possibly via `fork`.  If anyone has examples of how to do this with either package or via another method, that would be great.  I think that solving any of these three use cases would solve all of them, modulo a little bit external code.

---

Note 1: I realize, [per this answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689900/pass-commands-to-an-running-r-runtime/2693059#2693059) that R is single threaded, which is why I suspect `fork` and Rserve may work.  However, I'm not sure about feasibility if one is interfacing with an R terminal.  Although R's REPL is attached to the input from the console, I am trying to either get around this or mimic it, which is where `fork` or `Rserve` may be the answer.

Note 2: For those familiar with event handling / eventing methods, that would solve everything, too.  I've just not found anything about this in R.

---

Update 1: I've found that the manual for writing R extensions [has a section referencing event handling](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Meshing-event-loops), which mentions the use of `R_PolledEvents`.  This looks promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends whether you want to interrupt idling or working R. If the first, you can think of bypassing the R default REPL loop by some event listener that will queue the incoming events and evaluate them. The common option is to use tcl/tk or gtk loop; I have made something like this around libev in my [triggr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/triggr/index.html) package, which makes R digest requests coming from a socket.

The latter case is mostly hopeless, unless you will manually make the computational code to execute `if(evenOccured) processIt` code periodically.

Multithreading is not a real option, because as you know two interpreters in one process will break themselves by using same global variables, while forked processes will have independent memory contents.

Comment: Can you clarify your 2nd paragraph?  I am happy to have something check a state periodically.  +1 for the suggestions on tcl/tk and gtk.  I'll definitely look at `triggr` and see if I can adapt it or the ideas.

Comment: I looked at `triggr`, but I suppose I will need to look at the tcl/tk or gtk methods, as you suggest.

Answer (score 9):

One more option is the [svSocket package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=svSocket). It is non blocking.

Here is an [8 minute video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvT8XThGA8o) using it, which has over 3,000 views. It shows how to turn an R session into a server and how to send commands to it and receive data back. It demonstrates doing that even while the server is busy; e.g., say you start a long running process and forget to save intermediate results, you can connect to the server and fetch the results (before it has finished) from it.

Comment: +1 Thanks!  It looks like it is just what I'm looking for. I wonder if I've used it before, as its behavior looks like something I'd had in mind.  I'll give it a whirl and see if it works out.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the package `Rdsm` supports this as well.

With this package, one can set up a server/client relationship between different instances of R, each is a basic R terminal, and the server can send messages, including functions, to the clients.

Transformed to the use case I described, the server process can do whatever monitoring is necessary, and then send messages to the clients.  The documentation is a little terse, unfortunately, but the functionality seems to be straightforward.

If the server process is, say, monitoring a connection (a file, a pipe, a URL, etc.) on a regular basis and a trigger is encountered, it can then send a message to the clients.

Although the primary purpose of the package is shared memory (which is how I came across it), this messaging works pretty well for other purposes, too.

---

Update 1: Of course for message passing, one can't ignore MPI and the `Rmpi` package.  That may do the trick, but the `Rdsm` package launches / works with R consoles, which is the kind of interface I'd sought.  I'm not yet sure what `Rmpi` supports.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. Run R from within another language's script (this is possible, for example, in Perl using [RSPerl](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPerl/)) and use the wrapping script to launch the listener.
2. Another option may be to run an external (non-R) command (using `system()`) from within R that will launch a listener in the background.
3. Running R in batch mode in the background either *before* launching R or in a separate window.

   For example:

   > R --no-save < listener.R > output.out &

   The listener can send an approraite email when the event occurs.